# gwt 2.7 ie8 blank page

Tags: internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest, gwt-2.7

I'm not asking for a solution but for an explanation.

Here is the point : i got blank page with GWT 2.7 using IE8. This problem appears after 2.4 to 2.7 gwt migration.

I solve it ticking the internet explorer option Tools > Internet Options > Advanced, scrolling down to security and ticking the box next to Enable Native XMLHTTP Support.

Does someone has an idea of what should have change between GWT 2.4 and 2.7 to create this problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had the same, when I migrated from 2.6 to 2.7.. Thanks for solution!